# JPA many to many relation in Spring Boot app doesn't work

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I want to create a many to many relation in my application but it doesen't work.

My first entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String location;
    private String email;
    private String status;
    private String role;
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    private LocalDateTime modifiedOn;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons")
    private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<Team>();
```

My second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Team")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String city;
    private Integer headcount;
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    private LocalDateTime modifiedOn;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "persons_teams",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teamId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personId"))
    private Set<Person> people = new HashSet<>();
```

I don't know what is wrong but the program doesn't compile.

Please help.

Comment: What error message or stacktrace do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In Person class you have indicated the name of field to be mapped in Team by using name "persons" but the actual field name in Team class is "people".